# Processing large CSV file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

First time working with python and I'd like to know if there is a way to speed the processing of a CSV file I have.

Basically I'm using Pandas to read a CSV file and have a few things I need to do on each line.

The code gives exactly the result that I want, but I think it's taking too long to run.
For 1000 rows on my test CSV it takes ~40 seconds to run, and 400 seconds on a 10000 rows one, but I would have to run it in a CSV containing over a million rows.

I'll add a pseudo code below:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]), "Desktop")
dados = pd.read_csv(desktop + '\\test-1000-rows.csv')
for i, row in dados.iterrows():
    #for each item in a list
       #check if row[column_a] or row[column_b] has the item as value
          #add row[column_c] to a list if true
```

Is there a way to speed up this processing? Am I using pandas wrong or something?

Comment: Why are you using pandas at all?  Pandas is a large library that has a lot of extra stuff you probably don't need.  There are other, much lighter-weight ways to read csv files.

Comment: In the task “add row[column_c] to a list if true”, is this the same list, that you're trying to check whether it contains `row["column_a"]` or `row["column_b"]`? Or is this a different list?

Comment: "I'll add a pseudo code below:" **no**. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnGordon as I said, it´s my first time using python, so when I searched on how to proceed while working with large csv files pandas kept getting mentioned everywhere, so I thought it would be like a default library to use for such a task and it would have better performance overall

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, I'll edit the post with a minimal reproducible example as soon as I have access to the code in a few hours. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance the red flag is iterrows(). You should avoid using iterrows() and apply() in most cases, as they are slow and eat up a good chunk of time. See [Does pandas iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues)

Pandas can preform operations on columns quickly so you should try and use vectorzied operations as much as possible.

```
'''
# An example of a vectorized operation
df['new_column'] = df['existing_column'] + 1
'''
```

I would start here. If you are still not happy with the speed you can look into other solutions such as 'chunksize' to read the CSV in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 2):

how about this ?

```
# vectorized operations to check for the items in column_a and column_b
mask = dados['column_a'].isin(items_to_check) | dados['column_b'].isin(items_to_check)

# extract the values from column_c where the condition is True
selected_values = dados.loc[mask, 'column_c'].tolist()
```